# How do you ask someone how their day at work is going?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

Would you say:

> Comment était votre journée au travail?

Comment: *Ça s'est bien passé, ta journée au boulot ?*

Comment: @jlliagre thanks!! and you could say that while they are still at work, it doesn't have to be after they are finished?

Comment: It does indeed.

Answer (score 5):

"était" implies that the work day is over.

You could say:

> Comment se passe ta journée (au boulot/ au travail) ?

If you don't mention "au boulot/au travail", that's implicit in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with the option *(au boulot / au travail)* as I think that we don't want to focus on work aspect only and take the whole day as such.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an american tradition. One can translate it but no french speaker would talk like that.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord. On demande la même chose en France, mais parfois avec des mots différents.

Answer (score 1):

A better phrase would be :

> Comment s'est passée votre journée de travail ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't refer to work explicitly, but ask, "How is it going?" -- *Comment ça va ?* -- or, *Ça va bien ?* -- or just, *Ça va ?*

If I wanted to ask for a detailed report about work, maybe, *Elle était comment, votre journée au travail ?*

*Ça s'est bien passé, ta journée au boulot ?* invites a one word answer (and is familiar, using *ta* instead of *votre*).

Note that *était* is past tense ("was"), which doesn't match the title of the question ("is going", present tense).

Comment: *Il était comment, votre journée* is a typical native English speaker French mistake ;-)

Comment: Is it? :-) I'm trying to [learn to be less formal](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/27195/5753), but (according to your criticism) I haven't got the hang of it properly.

Comment: You are missing the gender issue!

Comment: Thank you. It used to amaze me that I knew the genders of words; but now, after 40 years of not using French, that ability is not reliable any more.

Comment: About formality, the reason why I used *tu* in my comment is I guess you are much more likely to ask this question to your partner, child, parent or other family member, a friend or a colleague instead of someone you *vouvoie*.