# Simple inversion with “je”

Tags: prononciation, questions, inversion

I think that for reasons of sound, the inversion of *je*, as in *aimé-je*? *prends-je*?, etc. is fairly rare and the *est-ce que* construction is being preferred in speech and writing alike.

But I also think that *ai-je*, *dis-je*, *fais-je*, *suis-je*, *vais-je*, *vois-je*, *veux-je*, *puis-je* are more frequently encountered.

1. What is the correct way of pronouncing *je* in the above structures?
2. When can we employ correctly the structures *dis-je ?* *puis-je ?*, etc. ?
3. I saw somewhere that after the orthography reform of 1990 the form “aimè-je” is also accepted. Is that correct? If so, why? Is the pronunciation still the same?

Comment: See also [Is “la forme interrogative directe inversée” not used in speech?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/27195/5753)

Comment: Also see [this thread](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24876/extra-vowel-before-inverted-je)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. *Je* is pronounced at the end of the syllable containing it. The ending *e* of *je* is generally silent but not in verses like *N'ai-je donc tant vécu que pour cette infamie*.
2. Essentially in written French. Sometimes also in formal spoken French, *puis-je vous emprunter votre stylo ?*

   Note that ***veux-je*** is quite rare and hurting many French ears. Some authors even use the barbarism ***voulé-je*** instead to avoid it...
3. Yes, the pronunciation is the same [ɛ]. The accent has precisely been changed to match it.